# .js extension for javascript file is missing

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using below code in my custom module "my_module".

```
    function my_module_theme(){
        return array(
                'my_module_javascript'=>array('arguments'=>array(),),
        );
 }

 function my_module_init(){
        theme('my_module_javascript');
 }

 function theme_my_module_javascript(){
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','my_module').'/my_module.js');
 }
```

After I enable the module page source is showing the javascript file without .js extension.
like src="modulepath/my_module?lrmjns"
Am I doing anything wrong? why is it skipping .js?

Answer (score 2):

What version you are using? And are you sure the my_module.js is exist?

I think the best way is using `hook_library` to add js and css for your module:

```
function my_module_library() {
  $libraries['my-module'] = array(
    'title' => 'My custom module library',
    'version' => '1.0',
    'js' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/my_module.js' => array(),
    ),
  );
  return $libraries;
}

function my_module_init() {
  drupal_add_library('my_module', 'my-module');
}
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, there is one more file being added with correct extension because of the typo in my .info file. By the way, is there any difference between these methods? drupal_add_js, drupal_add_library and script[] ='mymodule.js' in info file?

Comment: [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) is the low level to add a Javascript file.

script[]='mymodule.js' will always add Javascript file to Drupal, can't lazy load.

[hook_library](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_library/7) allow your module and other module can add Javascript, CSS file which version support in easy way and when you need to upgrade your Javascript source (and keep current source), only one modify need.